# Function taking Comma separated values in variable as a single string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I M trying to filter some product in product magento ce 1.7. im fetching the values what i wanna filter from multi dimensional array

```
foreach ($artist_productIds as $artist_productID){
    $artist_product_id[] = $artist_productID['mageproductid'];
}
$artist_prodIdString = implode(',',$artist_product_id);
```

and passing it into a magento  query

```
$categoryproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentArtCat)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
 ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('neq' => 2))
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array($artist_prodIdString)));
```

while debugging i fount that it passing value as

```
array('47,48,49,112,113,114,115,116')
```

it should pass like

```
array(47,48,49,112,113,114,115,116)
```

how should i solve it !

Comment: Try to explode this , with : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: try with double quotes in implode

Comment: why are you even imploding? You can pass the array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are imploding an array to string and then passing it

```
$artist_prodIdString = implode(',',$artist_product_id);
```

and then using as

```
array('nin' => array($artist_prodIdString));
```

You can pass the array directly as

```
 array('nin' => $artist_product_id);
```

which u generated in foreach.

If your $artist_product_id is not a proper array 
then after

```
$artist_prodIdString = implode(',',$artist_product_id);
```

make it an array using explode() and pass it to the function.

You are trying something as

```
$str = '47,48,49,112,113,114,115,116' ;
$array = array($str);
print_r($array);
output Array
(
    [0] => 47,48,49,112,113,114,115,116
)
```

Same is happening in your case too all the numbers are for the array key 0